# Unable to launch Jupyter Note from Anaconda Navigator(Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I launch anaconda from the command prompt using this code

```
anaconda-navigator
```

However, when I try to launch Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda, I receive this error code. Could someone help, please?

```
C:\Users\mxixq\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mxixq\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\mxixq\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 49, in 
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
File "C:\Users\mxixq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\mxixq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\mxixq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\mxixq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\mxixq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\Users\mxixq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\mxixq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Was it working before when you installed jupyter

Answer (score 0):

Use the 2019 version of Anaconda